# (React) How to Redirect to Result page on Search

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So im working on some project school and im stuck on building search bar so when i enter it doesnt want to go to my result page instead it goes to http://localhost:3000/Masing? heres the code

```
import { ReactSearchAutocomplete } from 'react-search-autocomplete';
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Search extends Component {

  state = {
    query: '',
    results: []
  };

  render() {

const { results } = this.state
const { props } = this.props

return (results.length > 0 ? <Redirect
    to={{
        pathname: '/Kerjasamaln',
        state: {
            results: results,
            from: props.location
        }
    }}
/> : <form>
        <ReactSearchAutocomplete
            className='search'
            type='text'
            ref={input => (this.search = input)}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
    </form>
 )
}
} 

export default Search;
```

any help i'd greatly appreciate it

Comment: Probably, props.location is undefined, please, print props to console and see the result